# I want to show the nested json on browser but something is wrong where I'm getting infinite nested and repeated output

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

```
this is Normal Pojo classes of Order and OrderItem
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Orders")

public class Order  {
    
    //@EmbeddedId
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int Oid;
    String name;
    double price;
    
    Order(){
        
    }
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "placeOrder",cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
    List<OrderItem> items;
    
    public void setItems(List<OrderItem> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
    public List<OrderItem> getItems() {
        return items;
    }
    
    
    Order(String name,Double price){
        this.name=name;
        this.price=price;
    }
    
    public int getOid() {
        return Oid;
    }
    public void setOid(int oid) {
        Oid = oid;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "OrderItems")@Data
@NoArgsConstructorpublic class OrderItem {
@Id@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int itemId;
    String itemName;
    String amt;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    //Since many records from here are attacted to some other table's one record
    @JoinColumn(name="Oid")
    //used to create the Foreign key relation with column name Oid
    Order placeOrder;
    //Oid 
    
    OrderItem(String itemName,String amt,Order order){
        this.itemName=itemName;
        this.amt=amt;
        this.placeOrder=order;
    }
    
    public int getItemId() {
        return itemId;
    }
    public void setItemId(int itemId) {
        this.itemId = itemId;
    }
    public String getItemName() {
        return itemName;
    }
    public void setItemName(String itemName) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
    }
    
}
```

Here this is my Controller and currently I'm not using the Services just the normal Repository(jpaRepository)

```
@GetMapping("/shoData/{Oid}")
Optional<Order> showOrderDetails(@PathVariable int Oid) {
        //Oid=2;
        System.out.println(Oid);
        Optional<Order> opOrder;
        
        opOrder=orepo.findById(Oid);
        System.out.print("demo");
        
            return opOrder;
            
    }
```

I'm getting output but the  Output is kinda messy actually its too much but I cut it down previously it was working totally fine but now dont know what happened suddenly

```
{"name":"patel","price":7899.0,"items":[{"itemId":4,"itemName":"cat","amt":"73","placeOrder":{"name":"patel","price":7899.0,"items":[{"itemId":4,"itemName":"cat","amt":"73","placeOrder":{"name":"patel","price":7899.0,"items":[{"itemId":4,"itemName":"cat","amt":"73","placeOrder":{"name":"patel","price":7899.0,"items":[{"itemId":4,"itemName":"cat","amt":"73","placeOrder":{"name":"patel","price":7899.0,"items":[{"itemId":4,"itemName":"cat","amt":"73","placeOrder":{"name":"patel","price":7899.0,"items":[{"itemId":4,"itemName":"cat","amt":"73","placeOrder":{"name":"patel","price":7899.0,"items":[{"itemId":4,"itemName":"cat","amt":"73","placeOrder":{"name":"patel","price":7899.0,"items":[{"itemId":4,"itemName":"cat","amt":"73","placeOrder":{"name":"patel","price":7899.0,"items":[{"itemId":4,"itemName":"cat","amt":"73","placeOrder":{"name":"patel","price":7899.0,"items":[{"itemId":4,"itemName":"cat","amt":"73","placeOrder":{"name":"patel","price":7899.0,"items":[{"itemId":4,"itemName":"cat","amt":"73","placeOrder":{"name":"patel","price":7899.0,"items":[{"itemId":4,"itemName":"cat","amt":"73","placeOrder":{"name":"patel","price":7899.0,"items":[{"itemId":4,"itemName":"cat","amt":"73","placeOrder":{"name":"patel","price":7899.0,"items":[{"itemId":4,"itemName":"cat","amt":"73","placeOrder":{"name":"patel","price":7899.0,"items":[{"itemId":4,"itemName":"cat","amt":"73","placeOrder":{"name":"patel","price":7899.0,"items":[{"itemId":4,"itemName":"cat","amt":"73","placeOrder":{"name":"patel","price":7899.0,"items":[{"itemId":4,"itemName":"cat","amt":"73","placeOrder":{"name":"patel","price":7899.0,"items":[{"itemId":4,"itemName":"cat","amt":"73","placeOrder":{"name":"patel","price":7899.0,"items":[{"itemId":4,"itemName":"cat","amt":"73","placeOrder":{"name":"patel","price":7899.0,"items":[{"itemId":4,"itemName":"cat","amt":"73","placeOrder":}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}
```

here I removed many lines but its too much and with this output my console is even cant load it
my Order table one row is Linked to the OrderItem table multiple rows

Answer (score 1):

Probably `OrderItem.placeOrder` points again to the same order the OrderItem belongs to. So you get a refence loop.

You may add annotation

```
    @JsonIgnore
    Order placeOrder;
```

Anyway, it is not a good idea to return entities in the controller.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/114226/petermmm thanks its works can u please explain me the problem in detail what happened

Comment: I would make sure to follow ur tip and can u please explain me how it is reference loop caused here

Comment: Mmm pretty obvious, Jackson will serialize recursively the whole object and any nested object: Order.items reference to OrderItem and OrderItem.placeOrder reference to Order. So it will serialize OrderItems again and again and again ...